# What does it mean: "to be in with a shot"

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

Just heard two phrases from a native speaker (Northern Ireland, UK):

1.

> we are still in with a shot

2.

> to be in with a shot

What do they mean? How would you explain the meaning of these phrases in English?

Comment: Please provide the context in which you heard the phrases. Otherwise we have no chance of helping you with a lot of guesswork.

Comment: "we still have a shot at winning" ="winning is not out of possibility" I suppose it's about soccer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"We are still in with a shot" means to still have a chance of winning or obtaining whatever the context is referring to.

Example:
You've just lost one game in a football tournament but you still have a chance of winning if you win the remaining games. Someone on the team may say to the rest of the team, "We are still in with a shot if we win our other games!"

Replace the word "shot" with "chance" and then try the phrases in the context you heard them. Do they work?

Sources:
1: Living in the UK.

2: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/shot
See point 6 in Nouns and points 2 & 4 in Phrases for examples of "shot" as synonyms of chance.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. ELU strives to provide objective answers. Thus you could improve your answer greatly by adding sources that substantiate it. Have a look at the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good answers.